# How to get raw XML back from lxml?

Tags: python, xml, html-parsing, lxml

I'm using the following code to locate a div:

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(page), parser)

div = tree.xpath("//div[@class='content']")[0]
```

My only problem is, that after doing this I do not want to rely on lxml to extract the contents of said div: I just want to get back the raw XML the div contains. Is this doable or do I have to abandon this method entirely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
etree.tostring(div)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `tostring`?

```
raw_xml = etree.tostring(div)
```